# How to convert std::string to System::String under Linux?

Tags: c++, mono

A very simple C++ question:

```
const System::String foo = bar
```

where `bar` is `std:string`.

How do I convert `bar` to `System::String`? I know there are many answers already, but they all seem to be based on Microsoft libraries, like:

```
System::String^ result = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(str.c_str());
```

I, however, don't have `marshal_as`. I need this to work under Linux (Ubuntu 20.04).

BTW, I'm not a C++ guy, so this whole thing is new to me.